# How to Insert BLOB Values

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I have the following table, FILES:

```
create table files(
id number,
file_name varchar2(25),
file_data blob);
```

I would like to be able to store data about binary files located on my computer in this table. However, when converting a file on my computer to hex, the string is too long to be inserted as Oracle will not work with string literals that have a length greater than 4,000. How may I insert a record into this table?

Comment: Maybe this [question on DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167449/how-to-insert-big-blob-data-in-oracle) can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually what you do is:

- You create an empty "Blob" object in your application.
- You insert the empty Blob into the database as one of the columns of the row.
- Then, in the same transaction, you retrieve an "output stream" from the Blob object you just inserted.
- You send data to the output stream until all bytes are sent.
- You close the output stream.
- You commit the transaction.

It's a really bad practice to load entire files into memory and then insert them into the database. Use streaming instead.